# Must declare a scalar variable.?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, charts

I have to display bar chart using ajax extender tool. I have to display information on chart when I am selecting one value from drop down list. But it shows "Must declare a scalar variable" error. Please help me.
Code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
              if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string query = "select Name from aTable";
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);
            ddlCountries.DataSource = dt;
            ddlCountries.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Name";
            ddlCountries.DataBind();
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
        }

    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
    protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = string.Format("select Debit, Credit, Year From aTable where Name=@Name", ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value);
        DataTable dt = GetData(query);

        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }
        BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y });
        BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
        BarChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("{0} Order Distribution", ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value);
        if (x.Length > 3)
        {
            BarChart1.ChartWidth = (x.Length * 100).ToString();
        }
        BarChart1.Visible = ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value != "";
    }
```

Comment: Include the full exception message/failure indicator, including the relevant line number and/or immediate stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
string query = string.Format(@"select Debit, Credit, Year 
                             From aTable where Name=@Name", 
                             ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value);
```

you have a parameter placeholder `@Name` but you don't add the required parameter to the SqlCommand that executes the sql. This produces the error that you see.
(By The way, string.Format requires the placeholder in the form {0}, but also if you fix that problem it is still wrong because you leave open the door to Sql Injection)

Fixing it requires a change in your `GetData` function.
You need to add an (optional) parameter array as another argument

```
private DataTable GetData(string query, SqlParameter[] prms = null)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            if(prms != null)
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

And now, when you call that method, you could write

```
string query = "select Debit, Credit, [Year] From aTable where Name=@Name";
SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
                          ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
DataTable dt = GetData(query, prms);
```

Notice also that I have put the field Year between square brackets. Year is the name of a T-SQL Function and you should use this trick to avoid to confuse the SQL Parser